# jquery toggle class not working in componentDidMount

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am working with a react component which includes jquery also.But one of the jquery functions `toggleClass` not working .

below is my code

```
export default class Dropdown extends Component {
 componentDidMount(){
  $('.dropdown-block button').on('click', (e) => {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().toggleClass('dropdown-show');
    console.log(e)
  })
 }
 render() {
    return (

        <div className={ this.props.position + " dropdown-block " + this.props.className}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>              
    );
 }
}
```

Here the button that is being clicked is a children of this component which is introduced in this component by `{this.props.children}` but `dropdown-show` class is not being added anywhere

Comment: Possiblity your buttons are not yet available in DOM when you are trying to add the listener, have you tried console.log($('.dropdown-block button')) just a line above where you are trying to add the listener in componentDidMount

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

[Usecase on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-x5ip9)

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(".dropdown-block>button").on("click", e => {
      $(e.currentTarget)
        .parent()
        .toggleClass("dropdown-show");
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={" dropdown-block "}>
          <button>Click me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

OR

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(".dropdown-block").on("click","button", e => {
      $(e.currentTarget)
        .parent()
        .toggleClass("dropdown-show");
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

OR

```
componentDidMount() {
    $(".dropdown-block").find("button").on("click", e => {
      $(e.currentTarget)
        .parent()
        .toggleClass("dropdown-show");
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you having correct version of jQuery in your project? Try in call in console $().toggleClass , if nothing is returned, that mean you have something overriding this function.